# Способ вывода значений Map на экран

Tags: java, java-8, задание-на-собеседовании

```
// При помощи коллекции получаем значения из Map и сортируем их по алфавиту
```

// Далее добавляем эти значения при помощи конкатенации строк в string, в том   // порядке, в котором эти значения получены из Map
for (List collection : map.values()) {
            collection.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
            for(String element : collection) {
                if (collection.size() != 1) {
                    string += element + " ";
                }
            }
            string += "\n";
        }

// Строка разбивается на массив строк с помощью регулярного выражения, для того, // чтобы вывести данные на экран в порядке, обратном добавлению в Map
        String[] array = string.split("\n");
        for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }`

Comment: Неужели за 3-и дня и ни строчки кода? Добавте в вопрос..

Comment: Вам не следует работать в этом месте, если вы не в состоянии за несколько дней решить несложную задачу самостоятельно.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void read(Path path) throws IOException {
    //  В с помощью метода exists() проверяется существование файла (пути)
    exists(path);

    //  Чтение данных из файла как последовательности строк с помощью метода Files.readAllLines
    //  и добавление всех слов в коллекцию List <String> rows
    List<String> rows = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);


    System.out.println(rows);
}

private String sort(String unsorted)
{
    byte[] bytes = unsorted.getBytes();
    String concat = "";
    Arrays.sort(bytes);

    for (byte aByte : bytes) {
        concat += (char) aByte;
    }
    return concat;
}

private String getFilePath()
{
    FileInputStream fileInputStream;
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    String fileUrl = null;

    try {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/config.properties");
        properties.load(fileInputStream);
        fileUrl = properties.getProperty("existingFile");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnex) {
        fnex.getMessage();
        fnex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchFileException nsex) {
        nsex.getMessage();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return fileUrl;
}

private static void exists(Path path) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    if (!path.toFile().exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Указанный файл не существует!");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    //  Получаем системное время на момент начала вычислений
    long beginning = System.currentTimeMillis();

    //  Создание объекта класса App
    App app = new App();

    // Создание и инициализация объекта Path с помощью вспомогательного класса java.nio.file.Paths
    // В теле вызваемого метода getFilePath() происходит считывание конфигурационного файла config.properties,
    // в указывается путь к текстовому файлу
    Path path = Paths.get(app.getFilePath());

    //  Вызов метода read, в теле которого будет происходить чтение из текстового файла
    app.read(path);

    //  Выводим на экран время работы в миллисекундах, в случаем успешного выполнения программы
    //  не входит в задание!
    System.out.println("\nВремя работы в миллисекундах: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - beginning));
}
```

}

Comment: Вы дополнили вопрос написав ответ к нему. Это не правильно. Ответы - для ответов. Вы можете дополнить свой вопрос через правку оного.